# CollectionView inside of StackView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an `UICollectionView` inside of an `UIStackView`. The `UICollectionViewCell` has an `UIImageView` which is pinned to the cell.

**What I'm trying to do here:**

- Showing the pictures which are picked by the user on the `UICollectionView` in a line.
- The `UICollectionView` would be horizontally scrollable (Thinking displaying pictures like on Twitter's posting screen.)
- The `UICollectionView` shows up only when the user adds a photo.
- Using the `UIImagePickerController` to pick up photos.

**Problems I got:**

- `UICollectionView` shows anything even after the user picks a photo to add.
- I don't even know it's the problem of code or `storyBoard`.

**What I tried so far. (All attempts had failed.):**

- Separate the `UICollectionView` and the `UIStackView`.
- Set the fixed width and height of the `UICollectionView`, `UICollectionViewCell` and `UIImageView`.
- Set a specific image of the `UIImageView`.

Here are my code and `storyBoard`.

**ImageCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

  // Avoiding showing cached image
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    cellImage.image = nil
  }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var albumTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pageTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bodyText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var frameStack: UIStackView!

var imageStore: ImageStore!
var images = NSMutableArray()
var selectedImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // UITextView
  self.bodyText.delegate = self

  // UITextFields
  self.albumTitle.delegate = self
  self.pageTitle.delegate = self
  self.date.delegate = self
  self.location.delegate = self

  // Create close button above the textView keyboard
  // Tool bar
  let closeBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 40))
  closeBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default  // Style
  closeBar.sizeToFit()  // Size change depends on screen size
  // Spacer
  let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
  // Close Botton
  let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(CreateVC.closeButtonTapped))

  closeBar.items = [spacer, closeButton]
  bodyText.inputAccessoryView = closeBar
}

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.contentSize = frameStack.bounds.size
    scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
  }

  // Enable textView to close
  @objc func closeButtonTapped() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }

  // Enable return key of UITextFields
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    albumTitle.resignFirstResponder()
    pageTitle.resignFirstResponder()
    date.resignFirstResponder()
    location.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
  }

  // Open up device's camera
  @IBAction func takePicture(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
      imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    } else {
      imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    // Place image picker on the screen
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // Open up device's camera
  @IBAction func pickPicture(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    // Place image picker on the screen
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // Get picked image from info directory
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Put that image on the screen in the image view
    selectedImage = image
    images.add(selectedImage!)

    imageCollection.reloadData()

    // Take image picker off the screen
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}

extension CreateVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return images.count
  }

  // Assign cells contents
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

    cell.cellImage.isHidden = true
    if let image = cell.cellImage.image {
      cell.cellImage.isHidden = false
      cell.cellImage.image = images[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
    }

    return cell
  }

}
```

[The Picture of my storyboard. The cell seems weird.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rzsp.png)

I'm kind of new to iOS development and completely stuck here.

**Further finding:**

I found the cell size looks weird.
Storyboard says the thing like this.

Cell
Expected: width 0
Actual: width 120

Comment: [updated]Make sure you have set the proper constraint for imageView

Comment: I agree with Matthew, you may not have the cell constraints properly configured. Are it's subviews correctly set up?

Comment: When it comes to the cell, I'm only using UICollectionView's "Cell Size" property because it seems unable to set specific constraints for the cell directly. And I pinned the UIImageView to the cell.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the problem. It was the cell's constraints. Here's how I solved this problem.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
  layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
  layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
  layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
  imageCollection.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

1. Set the specific height for the CollectionView on the Storyboard
2. Set the cell's constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method like above